# Microwaving chicken before frying

Tags: chicken, microwave

How long do I microwave chicken before breading it then frying it? I seen this being done on a cooking show, but missed how long the microwave part was. Thank you

Comment: Do you know if the intent was to fully cook it in the microwave, or was it just a little cooking that was supposed to help with the frying somehow? The first answer you've gotten seems to be assuming it's supposed to be fully cooked.

Comment: Microwaving meat and poultry tends to make it tough, I'd recommend a different method!

Comment: It was just to par cook it. I intended to bread (by double dredge) then fry. It worked out beautifuly. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microwaving raw meats is quite tricky, as its difficult to cook evenly. A different method would be best, sous vide probably being the most reliable. The machines can be pricey, but I've had good luck with a pot of water, a candy thermometer, and some ziplock bags (especially if you're only looking to par cook). You can find some great tutorials with a quick Google search.

If you have no option but the microwave, make sure that you  cook for short periods, rotating and flipping the meat often to prevent uneven cooking. I'd also recommend cooking in a container with a small amount of water and a cover of some kind (but not sealed) to take advantage of some steam.

Comment: Microwaving also works for small pieces because you can rearrange them every minute or so. The recipe could be for chicken nuggets.

Comment: Thank yo so much for the feedback. It was very helpful. My fried chicken turn out beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of folks that microwave a chicken to reduce the water that is contained in chickens you buy at the grocery store.  Many are loaded with excess water.  This can then affect the overall result and can explain why flour appears to be gummy on dredged chicken if the pieces are waiting for a while before their turn at frying.   Anyway,  the microwave time just to get rid of water is 1-2 minutes for a whole chicken before cutting it up into pieces.